# .net 4.61 httpwebrequest on all .tv domains fail, especially https://www.tvone.tv

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I am using .net 4.61 and doing a httpwebrequest with VB on https://www.tvone.tv and it fails to connect to server every time. Any other lookup on any other domain other than .tv works fine. I got http://ustream.tv to work once but only once and never again.

Is this a .net problem or a dns problem with .net?

IE, Edge, Firefox and Chrome all load the webpage fine from the computer I use to compile on. So, I know it isn't a network problem.

Is there a specific way I need to load .tv domains with httpwebrequests?

Comment: Try setting the User-Agent of your request. Some websites doesn't like clients that don't include one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48238304

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Keep in mind that sometimes it's something that the webserver requires that browsers usually implement, but httpwebrequest does not by default...such as cookies, requiring tls1.2, etc. Visual Vincent's suggestion is a good one to try too

Comment: I am getting a web exception of "cannot connect to server". I've now also tried www.fyi.tv and are getting the same results. Every other domain tld works fine.

Comment: I've also looked at the browser to see what headers it includes and I am matching them in code one for one and still get the failure to connect to host error.

Comment: These are the browsers that that I am setting user-agent for...

Comment: Select Case browser
            Case browsers.FIREFOX
                objRequestAll.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
            Case browsers.CHROME
                objRequestAll.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36"
            Case browsers.IE11
                objRequestAll.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
        End Select

Comment: Just tested both, they both work fine. The tvone site uses Tls 1.2 and no cookies, so you have to set `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` The other one just uses cookies (no Tls). You have to define a CookieContainer and add it to the HttWebRequest: `Dim _CookieContainer As CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()`  then `YourHttWebRequest.CookieContainer = _CookieContainer`. Your method should include both, to be of more general use. Also, set a UserAgent. Copy the FireFox one from the headers. it's fine.

Comment: Yep... Setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol works like a champ. 

I already had a CookieContainer set and adding cookies. Thanks for your help Jimi!

Comment: @Jimi : You ought to write that as an answer so that this can be marked as solved!

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Mah, do you think (know) that it matters? (Mind that I'm still really "green" here, so it's a real question:) I'm not sure what would be a good way to Convert.ToAnswer(this.Comment). Why don't you answer it, so I'll take it as a blueprint? You have commented first, anyway.

Comment: @Jimi : I might have commented first but you were the one that found the solution. He was already setting a User-Agent and a CookieContainer. The missing piece of the puzzle was `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` (like you suggested in your comment). To convert it into an answer you pretty much just have to say what you said in the comment: The site(s) uses TLS 1.2 so he's got to change `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` and set a `CookieContainer` to cover both options. :)

Comment: @Jimi : Answers _don't_ have to be perfect 20-page essays ;). Most of the time pointing out what is wrong and how to fix it is enough. The important thing is _the information_ that an answer delivers. In many cases (like your comment) just a few sentences is enough to provide quality information that gives you a better understanding of what the problem is and how it can be fixed.

Comment: @Visual Vincent  So, I decided to translate the comment in an answer. Came out a freak show, I think. But I'm pinging because you didn't answer to the "does it matter" part. I mean, do SO, the community, count - for statistical reasons of what else - on a traceable number of answers vs. the number of questions posted here? Or, yes, a comment can solve a problem, but doesn't add to the numbers (it can't be counted and/or reported as a succesful result). So, it's not statistically significant.

Comment: @Jimi : What SO (both the community and the site) mainly cares about is that each (useful) question has an at least equally useful answer. It most certainly is **not** for statistical reasons, but rather that it fulfills the site's purpose of being a Q&A site _**and**_ an "internet library" for programmers. We want questions (and/or answers) that not only help the OP, but that are also helpful for _other programmers_ that come looking for solutions here (either directly on the site or simply getting directed here via Google).

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Thanks, that's useful. It happend a number of times to solve a question through comments. I never thought about posting an answer after. It though it was enough. That's why I'm pestering you with questions. (Now I'm stopping, though :)

Comment: @Jimi : It's always okay to ask questions, and I'm happy to answer them ;). It's good that you want to learn how the site works. There are plenty of users out there that don't care about it at all and does everyting according to how they _think_ it works (or should work). -- It's not wrong to happen to answer a question with a comment, but if it really answered the question then it is always encouraged to rewrite it as answer, even if it's a simple one. Otherwise others that come looking a solution to a similar (or the same) problem might not see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the sites you mentioned had a `Https:` schema in the URI.
This implies that a security protocol is used. Upon inspection, this site uses TLS 1.2 security protocol. So you may need to enable it (required in Windows 7 when targeting a .Net Framework version prior to 4.8, usually not required in Windows 10, since it's the default), setting the  [ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager) [SecurityProtocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Also, most of the time, sites use Cookies (or *have* to use them, because external resources require them to. Google tools, for example).
You have to provide means to accept, store and exchange them.
This is accomplished instantiating a [CookieContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecontainer) and passing it to the [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest) using its [CookieContainer Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer) Property.

---

So I tested all of them to see what was happening behind the curtains (see the results).

One of them is more interesting than the others, (`https://www.tvone.tv`). It's one of those that don't accept a schema other than `Https:`. If you change it, it will redirect your request back to it (forcing security with Tls 1.2 certificate exchange). But it doesn't (the home page, at least) use cookies.
Since I think it's somewhat interesting, I'm posting the code used for testing. If, in the Headers setup, you set `.AllowAutoRedirect = False`, you can follow the redirection and see what it does.

> Host URI: https://tvone.tv/ - IP Address: 45.79.161.20
> Http Protocol: Http/1.1
> Response Status: OK
> Cookies n°: 0
> Security Protocol: Tls 1.2

*Try this with `Https:` schema*

> Host URI: http://www.ustream.tv/ - IP Address: 199.66.238.212
> Http Protocol: Http/1.1
> Response Status: OK
> Cookies n°: 2
> Security Protocol: N/A

> Host URI: http://www.fyi.tv/ - IP Address: 151.101.14.168
> Http Protocol: Http/1.1
> Response Status: OK
> Cookies n°: 1
> Security Protocol: N/A

This is the code used for testing.
(It's a redacted/translated redux of a library of mine, so you don't have to worry about stepping on anyone's toes if you use it).

The main function, `HTTP_GetWebPageAsync()`, can be called like this:
(The object passed is returned with its properties filled with the data shown in the results above, plus the whole Html page (in `Public Property PayLoad`) of the response).

```
Dim httpReqObject As HttpReqObj = New httpReqObject()
Dim maxWaitTimeOut As Integer = 30  'Seconds
httpReqObject.SiteURL = "https://tvone.tv/"
httpReqObject = Await HTTP_GetWebPageAsync(httpReqObject, maxWaitTimeOut)
```

---

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Authentication
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Text

Private Const COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION As Int32 = &H80131509

Public Class HttpReqObj
    Public Property SiteURL As String
    Public Property StatusCode As HttpStatusCode
    Public Property PayLoad As String
    Public Property Cookies As CookieContainer
    Public Property HostAddress As IPAddress()
    Public Property HttpProtocol As String
    Public Property SslProtocol As SslProtocols
End Class

Public Async Function HTTP_GetWebPageAsync(HttpSite As HttpReqObj, ReqTimeOut As Integer) As Task(Of HttpReqObj)
    Dim httpRequest As HttpWebRequest
    Dim cookiejar As New CookieContainer()
    Dim statusCode As HttpStatusCode
    Dim redirectURL As String = String.Empty
    Dim referer As String = String.Empty
    Dim payload As String = String.Empty
    Dim maxAwaitableTimeout As Integer = ReqTimeOut
    Dim maxHops As Integer = 40

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf TlsValidationCallback

    Try
        httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(HttpSite.SiteURL)
        HttpSite.HostAddress = Await Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(httpRequest.Host)
        HTTP_RequestHeadersInit(httpRequest, cookiejar, "")
        httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get

        Using httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(Await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync(), HttpWebResponse)
            statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode
            payload = If(statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, ProcessResponse(httpResponse, HttpSite), String.Empty)
            redirectURL = URIFromResponseLocation(httpResponse).ToString()
            HttpSite.HttpProtocol = "Http/" + httpRequest.ProtocolVersion.ToString()
        End Using

        'On Page Redirection, follow redirections [maxHops] hops and maxAwaitableTimeout] time
        If (redirectURL <> HttpSite.SiteURL) Or 
           (statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Moved) OrElse
           (statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found) OrElse
           (statusCode = HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod) Then

               If (redirectURL <> HttpSite.SiteURL) Then
                   Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()
                   sw.Start()

                   referer = HttpSite.SiteURL
                   HttpSite.SiteURL = redirectURL
                   httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(HttpSite.SiteURL)
                   httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
                   HTTP_RequestHeadersInit(httpRequest, cookiejar, referer)

                   Dim hops As Integer = 1
                   Do
                        Using httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(Await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync(), HttpWebResponse)
                            payload = ProcessResponse(httpResponse, HttpSite)
                            statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode
                            redirectURL = URIFromResponseLocation(httpResponse).ToString()
                        End Using

                        If redirectURL <> HttpSite.SiteURL Then
                            If (statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Moved) OrElse
                               (statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found) OrElse
                               (statusCode = HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod) Then

                                HttpSite.SiteURL = redirectURL
                                httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(HttpSite.SiteURL)
                                HTTP_RequestHeadersInit(httpRequest, cookiejar, referer)
                                hops += 1
                            End If
                        End If

                        If sw.Elapsed.Seconds > maxAwaitableTimeout Then
                            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout
                            Exit Do
                        End If

                   Loop While (statusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK) AndAlso (hops < maxHops)
                sw.Stop()
            End If
       End If
    Catch exW As WebException
        statusCode = If(exW.Response IsNot Nothing, 
                        CType(exW.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode,
                        CType(exW.Status, HttpStatusCode))
        payload = String.Empty
    Catch exS As System.Exception
        If exS.HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION Then
            statusCode = CType(WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure, HttpStatusCode)
        Else
            statusCode = CType(WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled, HttpStatusCode)
        End If
        payload = String.Empty
    Finally
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Nothing
    End Try

    HttpSite.Cookies = cookiejar
    HttpSite.PayLoad = payload
    HttpSite.StatusCode = statusCode

    Return HttpSite
End Function


Private Function TlsValidationCallback(sender As Object, CACert As X509Certificate, CAChain As X509Chain, ssl_PolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    If ssl_PolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.None Then
        Return True
    End If

    Dim _Certificate As New X509Certificate2(CACert)
    'Dim _CACert As New X509Certificate2("./ca.cert")  'Add your certificate here
    'CAChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(_CACert)
    CAChain.Build(_Certificate)
    For Each CACStatus As X509ChainStatus In CAChain.ChainStatus
        If (CACStatus.Status <> X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError) And
           (CACStatus.Status <> X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function

Private Function ExtractSslProtocol(stream As Stream) As SslProtocols
    Dim flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static

    Dim objConnection = stream.[GetType]().GetField("m_Connection", flags).GetValue(stream)
    Dim objTlsStream = objConnection.[GetType]().GetProperty("NetworkStream", flags).GetValue(objConnection)
    Dim objSslState = objTlsStream.[GetType]().GetField("m_Worker", flags).GetValue(objTlsStream)
    Return CType(objSslState.[GetType]().GetProperty("SslProtocol", flags).GetValue(objSslState), SslProtocols)
End Function


Private Sub HTTP_RequestHeadersInit(ByRef HttpReq As HttpWebRequest, CookieJar As CookieContainer, Referer As String)
    HttpReq.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 30000
    HttpReq.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False
    HttpReq.Timeout = 30000
    HttpReq.CookieContainer = CookieJar
    HttpReq.KeepAlive = True
    HttpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    HttpReq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    HttpReq.Referer = Referer
    HttpReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
    HttpReq.Accept = "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    HttpReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.5")
    HttpReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8")
    HttpReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0")
End Sub

Private Function ProcessResponse(Response As HttpWebResponse, HttpSite As HttpReqObj) As String
    Dim html As String
    Dim enc As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8

    Try
        If Response.CharacterSet.Length > 0 Then 
            enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(Response.CharacterSet)
        End If

        Using rstream As Stream = Response.GetResponseStream()
            HttpSite.SslProtocol = ExtractSslProtocol(rstream)
            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                If Response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip") Then
                    Using gzip As New Compression.GZipStream(rstream, Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
                         gzip.CopyTo(ms)
                    End Using
                ElseIf Response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate") Then
                    Using deflate As New Compression.DeflateStream(rstream, Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
                         deflate.CopyTo(ms)
                    End Using
                Else
                    rstream.CopyTo(ms)
                End If

                ms.Position = 0
                Using reader As New StreamReader(ms, enc)
                    html = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch _Ex As Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try

    Return html
End Function

Private Function URIFromResponseLocation(RefResponse As HttpWebResponse) As System.Uri
    Dim url As Uri
    Dim loc As String = RefResponse.Headers("Location")

    Try
        If Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(loc, UriKind.Absolute) Then
            url = New Uri(loc, UriKind.Absolute)
        Else
            Dim hostUri As String = RefResponse.ResponseUri.GetComponents(
                UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped) + loc
            If Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(hostUri, UriKind.Absolute) Then
                url = New Uri(hostUri)
            Else
                url = New Uri(RefResponse.ResponseUri.GetComponents(
                    UriComponents.Scheme, UriFormat.Unescaped) +
                    RefResponse.ResponseUri.Host + loc
                )
            End If
        End If
    Catch _Ex As Exception
        url = New Uri(loc, UriKind.Relative)
    End Try

    Return url
End Function
```

Comment: After reading this a second time I realized that the solution is not as clear as in your comment. You might want to add specifically what _he_ needs to change as well in order to solve his problem, not only the code to how you got there :). (Mainly I'm talking about that he needs to change to TLS 1.2, as you already mentioned the `CookieContainer`)

Comment: @Visual Vincent Right, I didn't write about `ServicePointManager` in the answer (told you, not very good at this yet :). I'll make the update.

Comment: That had nothing to do with not being good at something... It was just a simple oversight, happens to everyone sometimes. At least it proves you are human. ;)

Comment: @Visual Vincent Do you think that all the stuff I added (after the <HR> line) is of some use here, or I better cut it all out and just leave the relevant part?

Comment: It's a bit of a limbo... I find it interesting to see how one came up to a solution, but not all people do. Though it is a rather interesting inspection code you have there so I say you should leave it for those who are interested in such things. :)

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Thanks. I appreciate your feedback. I was asking because I noticed that SO users mostly appreciate very short answers. It seemed a bit odd at first, given the, almost, code-only policy of the site (where code ought to be paramount). Of course you can surely consider those straight-to-the-point answers. It made me think nonetheless.